# Classic ASP - Query Execution Process

Tags: asp-classic

I have created a Procedure to execute the set of queries.
In the SQL, the query takes 30sec to execute where as when I call the same procedure in ASP page it takes more time to display the data.
Kindly give me a solution for the same.

Comment: How many records you select? What is the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Set up timers before and after each query, response.write it and compare it later.

example

```
response.write "<li>" & now
rs.Open "Names", connStr, , , adCmdTableDirect  
response.write "<li>" & now
```

find out which query is running the slowest.

but my feeling that they all take the same amount of time. the problem is in the back and forth rs("this") and rs("that") access, that is outputting the data into html.
when the web and the sql server are in different networks, communicating in between them takes a heck of a time.

As a remedy, you can use getrows.

http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/getting-away-from-recordsets-use-getrows-230953.html